# make a class element fixed to a position with responsiveness

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the below code which display nine boxes exactly inside a name board with responsiveness.

I have class **numberdisplay** which i want to display number inside a handing board.

`My problem is the the numberdisplayeddidn't displayed in hanging board is not responsive and fixed.
when window resizes the size an alignment changes.`

I **want the numberdisplayed to be fixed inside the hanging board and should be responsive.**

How can this be done and how to achieve this?

```css
.box {
  width: calc(33.3% - 4px);
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  border: #000 border-color: #e6e600;
  margin: -2px;
  border-radius: 10%;
  background-color: #99ffff;
}
.numberdisplay {
   margin-left:73.99%;

   margin-top:20%;
   margin-bottom:100%;
   background-color:#ffff00 2px;
   border:px solid #000066;
        }
.containerr {
  border: px solid #FF3399;
}

.pic {
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

p {
  font: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  background-image: url(https://image.ibb.co/eV5WW9/background.jpg);
  background-size: 100vw 100vh;
}

.box {
  height: 15vh;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center
}

.container2 {
  width: 35vw;
  position: fixed;
  top: 41.5vh;
  left: 14vw;
}
.box p {
  font-size: calc(2vw + 10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container2">
  <div class="containerr">
    <div class="pic" id="content">
      <div id="container">
        <div class="box" id="10">
          <p name="values" data-item-index="0">1:40</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box" id="11">
          <p name="values" data-item-index="7">8:10</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box" id="12">
          <p name="values" data-item-index="4">5:35</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="2container">

        <div class="box" id="10">
          <p name="values" data-item-index="11">12:50</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box" id="11" >
          <p name="values" data-item-index="9" >10:40</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box" id="12" >
          <p name="values" data-item-index="11" >12:50</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="3container">

        <div class="box" id="10" >
          <p name="values" data-item-index="0" >1:40</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box" id="11" >
          <p name="values" data-item-index="3" >4:45</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box" id="12" >
          <p name="values" data-item-index="2">3:50</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="numberdisplay" id="2">
 <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=11" style="width:160px; height:160px; border-radius: 50%;" border="rounded"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The better option would be to have not one full background image, rather then have a `<div>` element with the board as the background image.

So you would not have those problems, because you want to resize your element based on the whole page background image. That's not the best solution in this case.

*EDIT* Something like tis:

```css
.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #AFFFDC;
}

.board {
  display: flex;
  /* replace me with the board .png image. Take also a look at the background: cover; property etc. to adjust the image size for different screens */
  background: #B1C296;
  /* I need the size of the board */
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  /* just for demo to show the container */
  padding: 10px;
}

.board--table {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.board--time {
  width: calc(33.33% - 4px);
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 10%;
  background-color: #99ffff;
  border: 2px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="board">
    <div class="board--table">
      <div class="board--time"><span>1:40</span></div>
      <div class="board--time"><span>1:40</span></div>
      <div class="board--time"><span>1:40</span></div>
      <div class="board--time"><span>1:40</span></div>
      <div class="board--time"><span>1:40</span></div>
      <div class="board--time"><span>1:40</span></div>
      <div class="board--time"><span>1:40</span></div>
      <div class="board--time"><span>1:40</span></div>
      <div class="board--time"><span>1:40</span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way i can schieve this in css?

Comment: can you show in your method, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't have photoshop, so i cant cut the two images. But i made a simple example , i edited my answer. Of course you would need to adjust it to your needs. But you get an idea.

Answer (score 0):

In your code `font-size: calc(2vw + 10px);` makes font size at least 10px; You must define font size only with `vw;` For Example `font-size: 3vw;`

```css
.box {
  width: calc(33.3% - 4px);
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  border: #000 border-color: #e6e600;
  margin: -2px;
  border-radius: 10%;
  background-color: #99ffff;
}
.numberdisplay {
   margin-left:73.99%;

   margin-top:20%;
   margin-bottom:100%;
   background-color:#ffff00 2px;
   border:px solid #000066;
        }
.containerr {
  border: px solid #FF3399;
}

.pic {
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

p {
  font: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  background-image: url(https://image.ibb.co/eV5WW9/background.jpg);
  background-size: 100vw 100vh;
}

.box {
  height: 15vh;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center
}

.container2 {
  width: 35vw;
  position: fixed;
  top: 41.5vh;
  left: 14vw;
}
.box p {
  font-size: 3vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="container2">
  <div class="containerr">
    <div class="pic" id="content">
      <div id="container">
        <div class="box" id="10">
          <p name="values" data-item-index="0">1:40</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box" id="11">
          <p name="values" data-item-index="7">8:10</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box" id="12">
          <p name="values" data-item-index="4">5:35</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="2container">

        <div class="box" id="10">
          <p name="values" data-item-index="11">12:50</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box" id="11" >
          <p name="values" data-item-index="9" >10:40</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box" id="12" >
          <p name="values" data-item-index="11" >12:50</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="3container">

        <div class="box" id="10" >
          <p name="values" data-item-index="0" >1:40</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box" id="11" >
          <p name="values" data-item-index="3" >4:45</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box" id="12" >
          <p name="values" data-item-index="2">3:50</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="numberdisplay" id="2">
 <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/75x75?text=11" style="width:160px; height:160px; border-radius: 50%;" border="rounded"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Mehdi, it would be good if you could explain a bit more the code you posted, so that it will be easier for users to understand your answer.

Comment: In your code "font-size: calc(2vw + 10px);" makes font size at least 10px; You must definre font size only with "vw"; For Example  font-size: 3vw;